# List prints square brackets in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

```
import sys
import string
import re
keywords = []
task = "*"
while task not in "ed":
    task = raw_input("Encrypt or Decrypt: \nType ‘e’ to Encrypt\nType ‘d’ to Decrypt\n").lower()
keyword = "*"
keyphrase = "*"
while not(re.match('[a-z ]+$',keyword)):
    keyword = raw_input("enter your first keyword:-").lower()
while not(re.match('[a-z ]+$',keyphrase)):
    keyphrase = raw_input("enter a key phrase:-").lower()

loop = 0
repeated_keyword = ""
if len(keyword) < len(keyphrase):
    while len(repeated_keyword) < len(keyphrase):
        repeated_keyword = repeated_keyword + keyword[loop]
        loop += 1
        if loop >= len(keyword):
            loop = 0
elif len(keyword) == len(keyphrase):
    repeated_keyword = keyword
    last_charecter_in_keyword = keyword[-1]
elif len(keyword) > len(keyphrase):
    repeated_keyword = keyword
    last_charecter_in_keyword = keyword[-1]
    while len(repeated_keyword) > len(keyphrase):
        repeated_keyword = repeated_keyword[:-1]    

repeated_keyword_letter_positions = []
keyphrase_letter_positions = []
for character in repeated_keyword:
    position_of_char_in_repeated_keyword = (string.ascii_lowercase + " ").find(character) +1
    repeated_keyword_letter_positions.append(position_of_char_in_repeated_keyword)
for character in keyphrase:
    position_of_char_in_keyphrase = (string.ascii_lowercase + " ").find(character) 
    keyphrase_letter_positions.append(position_of_char_in_keyphrase)

if task == "e":
    final_positions_of_letters = [a + b for a, b in zip(keyphrase_letter_positions,repeated_keyword_letter_positions)]
elif task == "d":
    final_positions_of_letters = [a - b for a, b in zip(keyphrase_letter_positions,repeated_keyword_letter_positions)]
new_letter = ""

final_cipher = []
loop = 0
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + " " + string.ascii_lowercase + " "
while loop < len(final_positions_of_letters):
    new_letter =alphabet[final_positions_of_letters[loop]]
    final_cipher = str(final_cipher) + str(new_letter)
    loop += 1
print final_cipher
```

This is a encryption/ decryption programme in python 2.7. However at the end of the programme when the final_cipher list is printed to the shell a pair of [] brackets are printed prior to the contents of the list

Answer (score 1):

You have some options here:

• Loop through the array, and print each element on the same row without delimiter.

• Use 'join' to join all the parts of the array in a single string. You can find more information about the join statement [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm).

Personally I do think 'join' is the best option here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to output a string. And you are making a mistake by setting the initial declaration to an empty list.

For fixing this just use :

`final_cipher = ""` instead of `final_cipher = []`

This should get you the output in string format.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing:

```
final_cipher = []
loop = 0
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + " " + string.ascii_lowercase + " "
while loop < len(final_positions_of_letters):
    new_letter =alphabet[final_positions_of_letters[loop]]
    final_cipher = str(final_cipher) + str(new_letter)
    loop += 1
print final_cipher
```

I see that you are working with `final_cipher` like a string, then you should initialize like:

```
final_cipher = ""
```

And:

```
final_cipher = str(final_cipher) + str(new_letter)
```

Should be:

```
final_cipher = final_cipher + str(new_letter)
```

Or better:

```
final_cipher += str(new_letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

`final_cipher` is a list, so yes, printing it will print it as a string, i.e. the result of calling `str(final_cipher)`.

If you want to just print the elements seperated by a comma, you can use .join:

```
print ", ".join(final_cipher)
```

Answer (score 0):

You create `final_cipher` as a list but then change your mind and do string concatenation instead. On the first iteration of the loop, `str(final_cipher)` creates the string representation of an empty list `"[]"`. Look familiar? Keep a list and build the string at the end.

```
final_cipher = []
loop = 0
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + " " + string.ascii_lowercase + " "
while loop < len(final_positions_of_letters):
    new_letter =alphabet[final_positions_of_letters[loop]]
    final_cipher.append(str(new_letter))
    loop += 1
final_cipher = ''.join(final_cipher)
print final_cipher
```